# Accessing translation data from geometry_msgs::TransformStamped

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to access the x, y, z values and quaternion values in a [geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.msg](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TransformStamped.html) , so my subsrciber looks like:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

void geoCallback(const geometry_msgs::TransformStampedConstPtr& pose){
    ROS_INFO(pose->transform.translation.x);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_subscriber_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/tf_static",1000, geoCallback);
    ros::spin ();
    return 0;
}
```

So while printing `float64 x` using `ROS_INFO` , I am getting error during compilation like error in printing `const _x_type&` , in particular error looks like:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/console.h:346:176: error: no matching function for call to _print(int, void*&, ros::console::Level&, const char [58], int, const char [50], const _x_type&)
```

So why it is saying `_x_type&` , instead of `float64` for `x` ? And how could I access the x, y and z value properly?
And this is my included header file [geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/geometry_msgs/html/TransformStamped_8h_source.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324674/accessing-translation-data-from-geometry_msgs::transformstamped/) by [warriorUSP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36100/warriorusp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2019-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> void geoCallback(const geometry_msgs::TransformStampedConstPtr& pose){
> ```

```
    ROS_INFO(pose->transform.translation.x);
}
```

There is a version of `ROS_INFO(..)` that takes only a single argument, but that argument must then be a string (well, a `char*` I believe, but basically a string), not a single `double` (`float64` is the name of the `rosmsg` IDL type, not a C++ type).

This is not Python, so you cannot just do `print (float(123))`.

As mentioned in #q12837, `ROS_INFO(..)` and the other `ROS_*(..)` logging macros support `printf` arguments, so in order to print a single `double`, you'd do something like:

```
ROS_INFO("%f", pose->transform.translation.x);
```

See also [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging - Log Statements](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging#Log_Statements).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [warriorUSP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36100/warriorusp/) on 2019-06-04**:
Worked like a charm.
But why it cant say `Expected argument is string but given double`, then debugging would be a lot easier.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
This is C++.

Additionally: `ROS_INFO(..)` is a macro, auto-generated and goes through a lot of layers before it comes to something that the compiler sees. At that point the context is completely different, making it hard to print such errors.

In any case: you should ask this of your C++ compiler team/oem/writer. Not on a ROS forum.